# Selenium Google Trends Custom period

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, google-trends

I am trying to get daily data from Google trends using Selenium.

Therefore, I need to Input the start and end date in both boxes. For the start date, I use the following which works fine:

```
elem4 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("md-datepicker-input")
elem4.clear()
elem4.send_keys("01/01/2018")
```

However, the second box has the same class name 'md-datepicker-input'. 
Picking it via xpath also doesnt work...

Has anyone an idea how to select that box, clear it and input my data?

[Example custom period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6WCk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS that you should use for `To` date.

```
.custom-date-picker-dialog-range-to .md-datepicker-inpt
```

[image]

If you want to use xpath

```
//div[@class='custom-date-picker-dialog-range-to']//input[@class='md-datepicker-input']
```

[image]